# 'Not all arguments converted during string formatting' for executemany()

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert multiple datasets through an INSERT command into a MySQL table. For this I defined following method:

```
def addRecords(self, records):
    """Add a list of shop -> filename entries into the records"""
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(records)
    self.cursor.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO foo_records ('shop_id', 'filename', 'missing_since', 'last_reported')
        VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), NOW())
        """, records)
```

When I execute this I get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` for the line calling `executemany`.

'shop_id' is an INT(11) at mysql and 'filename' is defined as VARCHAR(60).

The content of `records` looks like:

```
[(1234, u'foo.csv'),
 (1234, u'bar.csv'),
 ..
 (1456, u'foobar.txt')]
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: I had a dumb mistake at the SQL. The column names were embedded in `'`.  When I deleted them it worked with `%s` instead of `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the question marks. What happens if you use `%s` (as [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) specifies) instead:

```
self.cursor.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO foo_records ('shop_id', 'filename', 'missing_since', 'last_reported')
        VALUES (%s, %s, NOW(), NOW())
        """, records)
```

?

Comment: For this I receive `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''shop_id', 'filename', 'missing_since', 'last_reported')\n            VALUES (437' at line 1")` since the shop_id should be an integer, not a string. But when I set `%d` for the shop_id the error message is `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str`. I also tried to come up with a tuple where the shop_id is saved as a string. Then I use `%d` aswell. This does not work either.

Comment: MySQL provides `convert()` function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html) (e.g. `select CONVERT('1aa',INTEGER), CONVERT('0x120',INTEGER), CONVERT('10',INTEGER);` ). You can add it to your insert to convert your values to integers.